# How to enable/disable submit button based on some conditional visible input validation - vue

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, vuejs3

In my application, I have a sign-up form with four text inputs that all have validation rules. The submit button is initially disabled and only becomes enabled when all four text inputs are filled. However, one of the input fields will only become visible after a certain condition is met. In this scenario, the validation rule is not applied to the hidden input field, causing the submit button to remain disabled even after the other fields are validated. I'm not sure why this condition is not being applied to the submit button state.

Below is my `useSubmitButtonState` function for disabling/enabling the submit button:

```js
import { computed } from 'vue';

export default function useSubmitButtonState(field, errors) {
  const isButtonDisabled = computed(() => {
    let disabled = true;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
    for (const prop in field) {
      if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(field, prop)) {
        if (!field[prop] || errors[prop]) {
          disabled = true;
          break;
        }
        disabled = false;
      }
    }
    return disabled;
  });
  return {
    isButtonDisabled,
  };
}
```

I'm calling this function in my component to pass the state of the submit button:

```html
<script setup>
import { reactive } from 'vue';
import useSubmitButtonState from './useSubmitButtonState';

const formdata = reactive({
     txtInput1: '',
     txtInput2: '',
     txtInput3: '',
     txtInput4: '',
     enableInput: false, // based on this txtInput4 visible/hide
});

const { isButtonDisabled } = useSubmitButtonState(formdata, errors); // errors.txtInput1, errors.txtInput2 ... etc.
</script>
```

Please suggest how to omit the hidden input field validation and enable the submit button.

Comment: Can you add your html template as well, so it is easy to debug

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the same issue faced in this issue:

[Why nested objects are not reactive in Vue3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76471057/why-nested-objects-are-not-reactive-in-vue3/76473307#76473307)

Loosing reactivity through destructing assignments.

```
const state = useSubmitButtonState(formdata, errors);
```

```
 <submit :disabled="state.isButtonDisabled">
```